# Mount local drive to Google cloud shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

Google cloud portal provide this Linux console, is it possible to mount a local drive (Windows or Linux) to this remote Linux instance?

Comment: No, it is not currently possible to mount your local disk to the remote Google Cloud Shell instance.

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible on Gcloud SDK, use this command that underthe hoods uses sshfs:

```
gcloud cloud-shell get-mount-command {DIRECTORY}
```

The only thing is on Windows you cannot get it actually:

```
gcloud cloud-shell get-mount-command C:\Users\me\cloudshell\
```

ERROR: (gcloud.cloud-shell.mount-command) mount is not supported on Windows

Official documentation :

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/cloud-shell/get-mount-command